# what is the open attribute

Tags: html

I've run across the open attribute like so:

```
 $.attr('open')
```

Or like so:
     `<div open='whatever'></div>`

I can't seem to find documentation for this attribute. What does it do?

Comment: Not one I've ever heard of. Where did you find it? It could be a custom attribute (custom attributes are supposed to be named `data-*`, but some developers ignore that rule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used on a [`<details>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element) element, so your example with the `<div>` is not correct.

[HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#attr-details-open) says:

> The `open` content attribute is a boolean attribute. If present, it
>   indicates that both the summary and the additional information is to
>   be shown to the user. If the attribute is absent, only the summary is
>   to be shown.
>
> When the element is created, if the attribute is absent, the
>   additional information should be hidden; if the attribute is present,
>   that information should be shown. Subsequently, if the attribute is
>   removed, then the information should be hidden; if the attribute is
>   added, the information should be shown.

- [Browser support for `<details>`](http://caniuse.com/details)
- [And a little demo for fun](http://jsfiddle.net/f39wk/)